# How to replace numbers in a string?

Tags: string-manipulation, replacement

I have a long string list:

```
string = {"E:\\job\\a\\000251.png", "E:\\job\\a\\000252.png",
  "E:\\job\\a\\000253.png", "E:\\job\\a\\000254.png",
  "E:\\job\\a\\000255.png", "E:\\job\\a\\000256.png"}
```

Now, I want to add 2 to the file name base when the file base name is an **even number**. I mean, I hope to get such new string list:

```
string = {"E:\\job\\a\\000251.png", "E:\\job\\a\\000254.png",
  "E:\\job\\a\\000253.png", "E:\\job\\a\\000256.png",
  "E:\\job\\a\\000255.png", "E:\\job\\a\\000258.png"}
```

How to implement it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It seams that there has not been an answer involved with `RegularExpression` yet, which is quite efficient when dealing with patterns of strings.

```
StringReplace[string, x : RegularExpression["\\d*[02468]\\."] :> ToString[NumberForm[ToExpression[x] + 2, 5, NumberPadding -> "0"]]]
```

> ```
> {"E:\\job\\a\\000251.png",
>  "E:\\job\\a\\000254.png",
>  "E:\\job\\a\\000253.png",
>  "E:\\job\\a\\000256.png",
>  "E:\\job\\a\\000255.png", 
>  "E:\\job\\a\\000258.png"}
> ```

---

**Update**

As @yode pointed out in the comment, `IntegerString` is better here on the right-hand side of `:>`.

Comment: Doesn't work for "E:\\job\\a\\000298.png".

Comment: @CarlWoll How about now?

Comment: Now it doesn't work for "E:\\job\\a\\000998.png".

Comment: @CarlWoll ah, your are right

Comment: @CarlWoll How about now then?

Comment: @CarlWoll I think I am just developing a functionality yode did not ask of.

Comment: `StringReplace[string, 
 x : RegularExpression["\\d*[02468](?=\\.)"] :> 
  IntegerString[ToExpression[x] + 2, 10, 6]]` is more concise..

Comment: @yode Great! This is it! I succeeded in using regex for string patterns but somewhat unwell at padding 0s to integers.

Answer (score 7):

You could create a helper function (the point of the helper function is to avoid calling [`FromDigits`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/FromDigits) twice):

```
incString[s_] := With[{r = FromDigits[s]},
    If[EvenQ[r],
        IntegerString[r+2, 10, StringLength[s]],
        s
    ]
]
```

and then use this helper function in [`StringReplace`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/StringReplace):

```
StringReplace[
    string,
    i:DigitCharacter..~~".png" :> incString[i]<>".png"
]
```

> {"E:\job\a\000251.png", "E:\job\a\000254.png", \
>   "E:\job\a\000253.png", "E:\job\a\000256.png", "E:\job\a\000255.png", \
>   "E:\job\a\000258.png"}

Answer (score 4):

```
StringReplace[string, 
 a : NumberString ~~ "." /; EvenQ[FromDigits[a]] :> 
   StringPadLeft[IntegerString[FromDigits[a] + 2], StringLength@a, "0"] ~~ "."]
```

> {"E:\job\a\000251.png",
>   "E:\job\a\000254.png",
>   "E:\job\a\000253.png",
>   "E:\job\a\000256.png",
>   "E:\job\a\000255.png",
>   "E:\job\a\000258.png"}

Borrowing the three-argument `IntegerString` idea from Carl's answer with an alternative replacement rule:

```
StringReplace[string, a : NumberString ~~ "." :> With[{b = FromDigits @ a}, 
   IntegerString[b + 2 (1 - Mod[b, 2]), 10, StringLength @ a]] ~~ "."]
```

> same result

Comment: Maybe more concise `StringReplace[string, 
 a : DigitCharacter ~~ "." /; EvenQ[FromDigits[a]] :> 
  StringJoin[ToString[FromDigits[a] + 2]] ~~ "."]`

Comment: see [here](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/46739395#46739395) please.

Comment: @yode, if you don't have elements like `"E:\job\a\000258.png"` in your string list your more concise version would work too.

Answer (score 3):

Here is an approach without `StringReplace`. It is one function `f` that first destructures the file-name and has two more definitions: one for files with an even number and one for all others.

```
ClearAll[f]
f[str_String] := f[{str, DirectoryName[str], FileBaseName[str], FileExtension[str]}];

f[{str_, dir_, name_, ext_} /; ToExpression[name, InputForm, EvenQ]] :=
   With[{
     num = IntegerString[FromDigits[name] + 2, 10, StringLength[name]]
   }, FileNameJoin[{dir, num <> "." <> ext}]];

f[{str_, __}] := str
```

Now better test it properly since my last version was completely screwed up. I need to make Linux filenames from your strings since otherwise, Mathematica's file functions don't work here. On your Windows machine, this should not be necessary.

```
string = {"E:\\job\\a\\000251.png", "E:\\job\\a\\000252.png", 
  "E:\\job\\a\\000253.png", "E:\\job\\a\\000254.png", 
  "E:\\job\\a\\000255.png", "E:\\job\\a\\000256.png"};
string = StringReplace[string, {"E:\\" :> "/", "\\" :> "/"}]

f/@string//Column
(* 
/job/a/000251.png
/job/a/000254.png
/job/a/000253.png
/job/a/000256.png
/job/a/000255.png
/job/a/000258.png 
*)
```

Comment: I have the greatest admiration for your contributions. I am trying to follow your answer but I believe there is an error in the second definition of `f`. `num` is defined as a local constant in `With` but never used in the output. I would also appreciate it if you would show how to use `f` for the given example.

Comment: @JackLaVigne Oh my goodness. There was so much wrong in my code because I didn't clear `f` for testing. Thank you for paying attention! Would you test if it works on windows with the original definition of `strings`?

Comment: Works fine in Windows. I was thinking I had to `Map` the function `f`` over `string`. Thank you for the update and example. It is clear to me now.

Comment: It doesn't work for "/job/a/000258.png" where `f` returns "/job/a/0002510.png".

Comment: @CarlWoll If you are on Windows, then this seems to be expected. Filename separators are OS specific and Mathematica's functions don't work if you are on Windows and try Unix files.

Comment: Shouldn't "000258.png" -> "000260.png"?

Comment: @CarlWoll Ah.. of course. Not my day it seems.

Comment: Hopefully final version.